# где найти import setting в webstorm? В меню file/import setting его нет

Tags: webstorm

где найти import [image: введите сюда описание изображения]setting в webstorm? В меню file/import setting его нет.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте **File > Manage IDE Settings > Import settings**

Comment: File > Manage IDE Settings > Import settings - такого в меню нет. У меня версия WS 2019.2
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings - пишут также надо сделать

Comment: у вас, наверно, включена синхронизация настроек (settings sync или  settings repository). До версии 2020.3 этот пункт меню был недоступен при включенной синхронизации (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202548)

Answer (score 0):

Вот раздел в меню

[image: в меню]

Вот в глобальном поиске

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]